# Is it normal to receive employee benefits guide before an official offer letter?

Tags: job-offer

Yesterday, I have received a call from HR of the company I'm interviewing for. In the call, he mentioned some of the company perks and benefits w/o telling me whether they will offer me a job or not. Later today, I received an follow-up email from him with an employee benefit handout, still w/o offer letter. Is it normal to receive benefit package before officially offering a job? I'm confused right now...

Comment: Why are you confused? He's just telling you what the benefits are.

Comment: If he is telling you that, it is implicit that you are being considered for a position there.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually getting the benefits, are you? It sounds like you're just being shown the benefit information you'll have if you accept the job. It seems like HR is trying to sell you even more on the job before they make an official offer. This has happened to me before, as well. It doesn't seem particularly out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 2):

> Later today, I received an follow-up email from him with an employee
>   benefit handout, still w/o offer letter. Is it normal to receive
>   benefit package before officially offering a job?

I've had that happen to me several times.

I'm not sure it's typical, but I don't think it's abnormal either. It just seems to be a way to convey the breadth of the benefits the company offers. Some interviewers would rather hand out the list of benefits than talk about them in an interview.

At least in my case, it was always eventually followed by an offer.